# Use windity API in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use Windity Api in ionic 2

So i was refering the following link.
[widity api][1]

And from my ts file, i tried to append the js file into the html using code.

But i was getting error windytyInit  is not defined.

Is it possible to use this api in ionic 2?
What should i do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The movements of the maps are very satisfying! :-D So I decided to get it to work with ionic. In ionic the only point where we can add `<script>` tags is `src/index.html`. So we can start adding all of the things listed in the tutorial you linked in there.

First of all you add `leaflet.js` as the last element in the `<head>` of `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Then you have to add a `div` with the id `windity` in the `<body>` of `index.html`. I also wrapped it into a container div so we can "move back" the element (more on that later). We have to add it here (and not somewhere in our other templates) because we cannot control when the windy script needs it and our template may not be available yet, important is, that you add the element before the `<ion-app>` element, otherwise the map is loaded on top of your app (I also added a style property to make sure the map is not visible before we want it to be visible):

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="windyty" style="visibility: hidden"></div>
  </div>
  ...
```

And the last part you need to add from the tutorial are the init variable and the main function and the `boot.js` dependency:

```
...
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var windytyInit = {
      key: 'PsL-At-XpsPTZexBwUkO7Mx5I',
      lat: 50.4,
      lon: 14.3,
      zoom: 5,
    }

    function windytyMain(map) {
      var popup = L.popup()
       .setLatLng([50.4, 14.3])
       .setContent("Hello World")
       .openOn(map);
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://api.windytv.com/v2.3/boot.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then you need to make sure all the scripts, css and images to display the map are allowed in your content security policy (make sure you do merge this one with yours):

```
<meta 
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content="
    default-src gap://ready file://* * blob:; 
    img-src https://*.windytv.com https://*.windy.com 'self'; 
    style-src 'self' https://*.windytv.com; 
    script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://*.windytv.com https://*.windy.com https://www.google-analytics.com"
>
```

When you launch your app now the map is loaded, but below your ionic app. So on the ionic page where you actually want to display the map you need to "move" the tag we created in `index.html` to the template of your page. And here is how you do it:

You create a container element with an id in your template where you want to place the map:

```
<div id="windycontainer"></div>
```

And in the corresponding typescript class you put the following code into angulars `ngAfterViewInit()` method (you need to put it in a lifecycle hook where the DOM is already available, `ionViewDidEnter()` does work too for example):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  document
    .getElementById('windycontainer')
    .appendChild(document.getElementById('windyty'));
}
```

And in the `.scss` file of your page you add the following to style the element containing the map (and to make it visible of course). You need to make sure its wrapped in the selector of your page:

```
your-page {
  #windyty {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
}
```

**Now heres the thing:** If we move to another page now, the current page is destroyed by angular and our nice map is lost. To fix this we need to move our element back to its initial position before the page gets nuked, the `ionViewWillLeave()` hook is the perfect place for that:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
  document
  .getElementById('container')
  .appendChild(document.getElementById('windyty'));
}
```

Now the map is safe again outside of the `<ion-app>` and we can move it wherever we need it again.

**This is what my final result looked like:**

[image]

---

**Note:** There is for sure a more angular way to move around the tags. In general it is not a good idea to access the DOM directly with `document.getElementById` in angular but its good enougth to demostrate the concept.

Comment: Nice tutorial/answer! :)

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras, appreciate that!